# Pandas: Missing values from Yahoo Finance

Tags: python, nan, yahoo, infinite, datareader

Despite my search through this forum and other sources I still have no idea how to fix this problem.

Explain: I was running a script(below) for downloading prices for all stocks in FTSE MIB 40 in order to try the best cointegrated pairs. Unfortunately it seems that, when running the script (already working for other markets) it reports error for `nans` or infinite values. I tried to use dropna but it still has problem. Here my whole code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import coint
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
import yfinance as yf
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import seaborn

ftse_mib40=['A2A.MI','AMP.MI','ATL.MI','AZM.MI','BAMI.MI','BPE.MI','BZU.MI','CPR.MI','CNHI.MI','DIA.MI','ENEL.MI','ENI.MI','EXO.MI','RACE.MI','FCA.MI','FBK.MI','G.MI','HER.MI','ISP.MI','IG.MI','JUVE.MI','LDO.MI','MB.MI','MONC.MI','NEXI.MI','NXEN','PIRC.MI','PST.MI','PRY.MI','REC.MI','SPM.MI','SFER.MI','SRG.MI','STM.MI','TIT.MI','TEN.MI','TRN.MI','UBI.MI','UCG.MI','UNI.MI','US.MI']
ftse_yah=pdr.get_data_yahoo(ftse_mib40,start='2017-01-01',end='2019-09-27')
ftse_matrix=ftse_yah['Adj Close']
ftse_matrix=ftse_matrix.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan).dropna(how='all')

def find_cointegrated_pairs(data):
    n = data.shape[1]#cioè numero colonne
    score_matrix = np.zeros((n, n))
    pvalue_matrix = np.ones((n, n))
    keys = data.keys()
    pairs = []
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i+1, n):
            S1 = data[keys[i]]
            S2 = data[keys[j]]
            result = coint(S1, S2)
            score = result[0]
            pvalue = result[1]
            score_matrix[i, j] = score
            pvalue_matrix[i, j] = pvalue
            if pvalue < 0.02:
                pairs.append((keys[i], keys[j]))
    return score_matrix, pvalue_matrix, pairs
tstat,pv,coppie=find_cointegrated_pairs(ftse_matrix)
```

Finally one (very) stupid question: any idea how to locate all infinite/nan values in the matrix? Thanks and sorry for the long code

Answer (score 2):

To identify the number of missing values in each column of your dataframe you can run the following

```
pd.isnull(ftse_matrix).sum()
```

You'll see that you still have missing values in `ftse_matrix`

To drop them replace this

```
ftse_matrix=ftse_matrix.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan).dropna(how='all')
```

with this

```
ftse_matrix=ftse_matrix.dropna()
```

For [dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) the argument `how='all'` will only drop rows from your dataframe if all of the values in the row are missing

Comment: Thanks man it worked! Great and thanks for advices!                                                                  One last question: How to create a dataframe of two columns where the first is every tuple of 'coppie' and the second is their respective pvalues 'pv'?

Comment: not sure about what you want here. `coppie` is a list of 16 tuples, and `pv` is a 41x41 numpy array. There isn't really a straight-forward way to fit those into a dataframe as they are now